# How to make a UITextView full width and height of containing UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have `UITextView` that I would like to make the same height and width of it's container. It is in a simple `UIViewContainer`.
I tried doing the following:

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
    resultText.text = result
    resultText.frame = view.frame
}
```

This seems to work for portrait but not landscape.
All I am trying to do is make the UITextView take up all the space of it's container.

If I could find the answer in Objective-C I could easily translate it to Swift. I am just looking for the answer for iOS.

Comment: `UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)]` does not work?

Comment: @Ra1nWarden how do I take into account the height of the nav toolbar at the top?

Comment: @Johnston: Based on @Ra1nWarden solution:
`UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)]` This should take care of the navigation bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use auto layout
[image]

Then click add 4 constraints.

If any warning,
[image]

Click Update Frames

Answer (score 2):

Autolayout is your friend - It can be done easily using [Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html), or in code:

```
override public func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .None
    resultText.text = result

    // add vertical constraints to pin the view to the superview edge
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0.0-[resultText]-0.0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["resultText": resultText]))

    // add horizontal constrains to pin the view to the superview edge
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0.0-[resultText]-0.0-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: ["resultText": resultText]))
}
```